# MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod returns MethodInfo with the wrong type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

**Resolved, I was just being silly. I left out the problem in my first submission.**

I had been ending up nesting two list types because the function does List, and when I asked for a generic method with the same returntype, it nests them. I need a way to get at the Type of each element in the list.

Original question:

When I try to build a generic method through reflection, I get the wrong return type back.

Here's the original method.

(Within DomainRepository)

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    List<T> passedType;
    using (ISession s = Singleton.OpenSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction t = s.BeginTransaction())
        {
            passedType = s.Query<T>().ToList<T>();
            t.Commit();
        }
    }
    return passedType;
}
```

And here's what I'm doing with it:

(In a unit test)

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(DomainRepository)
                .GetMethod("GetAll")
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Domain.Entity));

dynamic genericResults = mi.Invoke(genericFactory, null);
```

When execution passes mi.Invoke, I get

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IList<Domain.Entity>>
```

when I believe that I should get

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.Entity>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

What if I wanted to generate a generic method and throw it into a dynamic type like this (which grew out of my inability to cast a non-concrete type)?

To clarify further, here is the whole test:

```
[Test]
public void TestDataAccess()
{

    var genericAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Data.DomainRepository));
    var genericFactory = new Data.DomainRepository();

    var types = from x in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ActivityFactory)).GetTypes()
                where x.Name.Contains("Factory") 
                select x;

    foreach (Type t in types){
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine+ t.Name +" : "+ t.BaseType.Name);

        if (t.BaseType.Name != "Object"){
            Console.WriteLine(t.Name + " inherits " + t.BaseType.Name +". Skipping." + Environment.NewLine);
            continue;
        }

        var getSingle_methods = from m in t.GetMethods() 
            where m.GetParameters().Count() == 0
            && m.Name.Contains("get")
            select m;

        object objectInstace = System.Activator.CreateInstance( t );

        foreach (var method in getSingle_methods) {

            if (method.ReturnType.FullName.Contains("Domain")){
                    Console.WriteLine(method.Name + " returns "+method.ReturnType.Name);

                    dynamic resultOfMethod = t.InvokeMember(method.Name, 
                                                        BindingFlags.Public |
                                                        BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objectInstace, null);


                    MethodInfo mi = typeof(Data.DomainRepository)
                                    .GetMethod("GetAll")
                                    .MakeGenericMethod(method.ReturnType);


                    dynamic genericResults = mi.Invoke(genericFactory, null);

//unfinished as yet
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you test the type? i.e what lines come after `dynamic genericResults...` ? Also: you might find it easier to use non-generic coding at the caller, i.e. `IList results = (IList)mi.Invoke(....);`

Comment: I'm just using the visual studio debugger with a breakpoint. Any access  of that type gets a "Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported"

The whole idea is that I want access to methods and properties contained within the list (automated object comparisons).

The reason I am using dynamic is because there is no clear way to know what type List<T> will return at compile time.

Comment: I think your code should work fine. You don't even use `IList<T>` anywhere, so I don't see how could you produce that. Also, can't you use generics instead of `dynamic`?

Comment: In the generic method, .ToList<T> is NHibernate's IList return type...

Comment: What does Query<>() return?  Not what you think, I guess.

Comment: Query<T>() is NHibernate's LINQ to NHibernate interface. It returns an IQueryable<T>

Comment: Aww I got it. Sorry! Using function's return type...